# A formula for length of representation of a number in a "base" without zeros

Tags: special-functions, combinations

If you had 2 items the sequence would go like this:
$$1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5, \ldots$$

This is $\lfloor\log_2(n+2)\rfloor$.

What if I wanted to do for 3 items which goes like this: $$1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,\ldots$$

A visual representation for $3$ items as $(A,B,C)$:

```
f(0) = 1:  A ──┐
f(1) = 1:  B   ├─ 3^1
f(2) = 1:  C ──┘
f(3) = 2:  AA ─┐
f(4) = 2:  AB  │
f(5) = 2:  AC  │
f(6) = 2:  BA  │
f(7) = 2:  BB  ├─ 3^2
f(8) = 2:  BC  │
f(9) = 2:  CA  │
f(10) = 2: CB  │
f(11) = 2: CC ─┘
f(12) = 3: AAA ┐
f(13) = 3: AAB │
f(14) = 3: AAC │
f(15) = 3: ABA │
f(16) = 3: ABB ├─ 3^3
f(17) = 3: ABC │
f(18) = 3: ACA │
f(19) = 3: ACB │
f(20) = 3: ACC │
...
```

Comment: It makes little difference for the answer, but perhaps it is more natural to write $A$ for $1$, $B$ for $2$, etc., rather than starting indexing at $0$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you noticed where the 'switch-over' points are?  That may help you craft a formula similar to the one you know for two items...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I tried but I didn't find a solution, I tried to find the sequence for 3 items in https://oeis.org/ and still there was no solution.

Comment: A broad hint: the transitions come at $3, 3+3^2, 3+3^2+3^3, etc.$  You should be able to find a closed form for these sums (the geometric series will be a help); then you can use algebra to find a proper inversion of it.

Comment: In fact, it is natural to identify the empty word $\emptyset$ with $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** The number of elements of length $k$ is $3^k$, so the number of elements of length $\leq k$ is $$3 + 3^2 + \cdots 3^k = \frac{3}{2} (3^k - 1) .$$ Thus, the $n$th element in the sequence $A, B, C, AA, AB, \ldots$ has length $k$ iff $$\tfrac{3}{2} (3^{k - 1} - 1) < n \leq \tfrac{3}{2}(3^k - 1) .$$

> Rearranging gives that the $k$ for which the previous inequalities hold is precisely $$\left\lceil \log_3 \left(\tfrac{2}{3} n + 1\right) \right\rceil .$$ Since the indexing in the question begins with $0$, i.e, since $a$ is the $(a + 1)$st number in the list, the function $f$ is $$f(a) := \left\lceil \log_3 \left(\tfrac{2}{3} (a + 1) + 1\right) \right\rceil .$$ It is straightforward to generalize this to arbitrary numbers of symbols $(A, B, C, \ldots)$.

Comment: Works. In any number of items is `floor((logn(i,(((i-1)/i)*n)+1)+1)`.

Comment: This will work for most values, but one should be a little careful, as $\lfloor x + 1 \rfloor = \lceil x \rceil$ iff $x$ is not an integer.